# Python Error EOF while parsing or syntax error

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
x = input ( "Hello what is your name : ")
print ("Nice to meet you " + x)
y = input ("Would you like to play Ted Ryan's Great Adventure Game? If you would like to play write yes if not write no")
y = yes
if y == "yes" print "lets begin"
```

What I am trying to is if the input for the question "Would you like to play Ted Ryan's Great Adventure Game? If you would like to play write yes if not write no" is yes I want it to print let's begin.

However, I sometimes get the errors "EOF while parsing" or "syntax error".

Comment: What is the fourth line doing? Read about the `if` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, You should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not `input`.

Input actually [`eval`'s whatever the user inputs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), which is why you get a `EOFError` if the user's name includes a single `'`, or a `SyntaxError` if their name isn't valid Python code.

--

Note that you seem to have an indentation problem on your last line. It should be:

```
if y == "yes":
    print "lets begin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. `y = yes` what is that line?
2. `x = input ( "Hello what is your name : ")` if you expect the user to input string you should be using `x = raw_input ( "Hello what is your name : ")` instead
3. if y == "yes" print "lets begin" should be -> `if y == "yes": print "lets begin"` with colon

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input ( "Hello what is your name : ")
print ("Nice to meet you " + x)
y = input ("Would you like to play Ted Ryan's Great Adventure Game? If you would like to play write yes if not write no")
if y == "yes":
    print ("lets begin")
else:
    print ("No we cant play")
```

Comment: Assuming it's Python 3

Answer (score 0):

try raw_input() instead of input

```
name = raw_input( "Hello what is your name : ")
print ("Nice to meet you " + name)
answer = raw_input("Would you like to play Ted Ryan's Great Adventure Game? If you would like to play write yes if not write no")
if answer == "yes":
    print "lets begin"
```